# Menu bars not integrated with Unity's global menu bar

Tags: appmenu

I upgrade from Lucid via `update-manager -d` and the upgrade went fine. However, I didn't get Unity's global menu. Windows stil have their indivual menu bars.

[image: Screenshot]

This happens for all applications.

Does this typically occur? Can this be fixed with a configuration setting?

Comment: is it for only firefox?

Comment: if this is only for firefox, what addons have you installed? Have you got `firefox-global-menu` package installed?

Comment: @fossfreedom This happens for any application and firefox-global-menu version 12.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is installed.

Comment: Have you got the indicator-appmenu package installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@fossfreedom was on the right track. On my system, the package `indicator-appmenu` (and `ubuntu-desktop`) was missing. Installing this package + restart solved the issue.

Comment: Jan, you are allowed (and encouraged) to mark this as The Answer™, even though you wrote it.

Comment: ubuntu-desktop is just a metapackage which you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

In dconf Editor [image: Install dconf-gsettings-backend] check for `com` → `canonical` → `indicator` → `appmenu` → `menu-mode` = "global":

[image]

Comment: is this 12.04 or 12.10?